# why my function doesn't remove objects from final_list?

Tags: python-2.7

hey guys:)im sorry for all the code but i feel its necessary for u to see everything..

i tried everything... i hidden prints in the code, debugging for ten times, triple checked the built in methods, and still,  the `.crawl()` method dosnt remove any object from the `final_list`.

the object of my assignment is to built two classes:
`Web_page` : holds data of a web page.(the pages come in the form of html files saved in a folder on my desktop. `Crawler`: compare between pages and hold a list of the uniqe pages---> `final_list`

```
import re
import os

def remove_html_tags(s):
    tag = False
    quote = False
    out = ""

    for c in s:
            if c == '<' and not quote:
                tag = True
            elif c == '>' and not quote:
                tag = False
            elif (c == '"' or c == "'") and tag:
                quote = not quote
            elif not tag:
                out = out + c

    return out


def lev(s1, s2):
    return lev_iter(s1, s2, dict())

def lev_iter(s1, s2, mem):

    (i,j) = (len(s1), len(s2))
    if (i,j) in mem:
        return mem[(i,j)]

    s1_low = s1.lower()
    s2_low = s2.lower()
    if len(s1_low) == 0 or len(s2_low) == 0:
        return max(len(s1_low), len(s2_low))
    d1 = lev_iter(s1_low[:-1], s2_low, mem) + 1
    d2 = lev_iter(s1_low, s2_low[:-1], mem) + 1
    last = 0 if s1_low[-1] == s2_low[-1] else 1
    d3 = lev_iter(s1_low[:-1], s2_low[:-1], mem) + last
    result = min(d1, d2, d3)

    mem[(i,j)] = result

    return result

def merge_spaces(content):
    return re.sub('\s+', ' ', content).strip()


""" A Class that holds data on a Web page """
class WebPage:

    def __init__(self, filename):

        self.filename = filename

    def process(self):

        f = open(self.filename,'r')
        LINE_lst = f.readlines()

        self.info = {}

        for i in range(len(LINE_lst)):
            LINE_lst[i] = LINE_lst[i].strip(' \n\t')
            LINE_lst[i] = remove_html_tags(LINE_lst[i])
        lines = LINE_lst[:]
        for line in lines:
            if len(line) == 0:
                LINE_lst.remove(line)
        self.body = ' '.join(LINE_lst[1:])
        self.title = LINE_lst[0]
        f.close()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '\n' + self.body

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title

    def __eq__(self,other):
        n = lev(self.body,other.body)
        k = len(self.body)
        m = len(other.body)
        return float(n)/max(k,m) <= 0.15

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.title < other.title

""" A Class that crawls the web """     
class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, directory):

        self.folder = directory

    def crawl(self):

        pages = [f for f in os.listdir(self.folder) if f.endswith('.html')]

        final_list = []

        for i in range(len(pages)):

            pages[i] = WebPage(self.folder + '\\' + pages[i])
            pages[i].process()

            for k in range(len(final_list)+1):
                if k == len(final_list):
                    final_list.append(pages[i])      
                elif pages[i] == final_list[k]:

                    if pages[i] < final_list[k]:
                        final_list.append(pages[i])
                        final_list.remove(final_list[k])
                        break

        print final_list

        self.pages = final_list
```

everything works fine besides this freaking line `final_list.remove(final_list[k])`.  help please? whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work, it's difficult to test it because I don't know what kind of input should end up calling `remove()`.

I suggest following these steps:

- Make sure that `remove()` is called at some point.
- `remove()` relies on your `__eq__()` method to find the item to remove, so make sure that `__eq__()` isn't the culprit.

As a side note, you will probably want to replace this:

```
self.folder + '\\' + pages[i]
```

with:

```
import os.path
# ...
os.path.join(self.folder, page[i])
```

This simple change should make your script work on all operating systems, rather than on Windows only. (GNU/Linux, Mac OS and other Unix-like OS use “/” as path separator.)

Please also consider replacing loops of this form:

```
for i in range(len(sequence)):
    # Do something with sequence[i]
```

with:

```
for item in sequence:
    # Do something with item
```

If you need the item index, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, item in enumerate(sequence):
```

Comment: thank u for your answer:)
but why i should replace the form of the loops?
i will do it on the first one no question asks..

Comment: but the second one who goes on the range of [len(final_list)+1] helps the function to know that if all comparsions made(  k==len(final_list)  ) then it append the current page to final_list

Comment: also. what's culprit?:)

Comment: ok i did another test and i can tell for sure that remove dosnt remove an item even thogh the function enterd the if condision

Comment: About the loops: it just makes the code more simple, and virtually all Python developers code this way. Sometimes, you have to resort to range(len(...)), but it should be avoided when possible.

Comment: By culprit I meant responsible for the bug. I guess that now you should check that `final_list` contains the item you want to delete, and then check that `__eq__()` works well. You can also rewite `final_list.remove(final_list[k])` as `del final_list[k]`.

Comment: again. thank u so much! so i checked, and final_list contains the item i shuold remove and i've hidden  print 'removed' after final_list.remove(final_list[k]) to make sure it gets to tht specific line. and on the out put u can see 'removed'

Comment: also i tried to replce remove() with delete and still, the same thing is happening.. any ideas what going on?